# The connection was closed unexpectedly error in sending message to bot api

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

We have c# application that use telegram bot API to send a lot of messages to a lot of subscribers using `SendTextMessageAsync`.

```
    await _client.SendTextMessageAsync(
                        telegramChatId,
                        message,
                        parseMode: ParseMode.Html,
                        replyMarkup: keyboard,
                        disableWebPagePreview: disableWebPagePreview,
                        disableNotification: disableNotification
                    );
```

It was working fine so far. But recently we started to get this exception for some of the requests:

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

or

```
The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.
```

The exception message doesn't give any clue about the reason.
Is there any way to have visual studio show more details!?
The program keeps working until about 400 first requests are sent.
As the number of requests exceeds 400, it is raising that exception while trying to make a request.
Also, there is a one-second delay between requests so we don't get `TooManyRequest` Exception.
It is no matter how many times we retry to send the request. I will get the same error again and again.

This is the stack-trace of exception:

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

and this is an exception stack trace:

```
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<MakeRequestAsync>d__54`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at MelkRadar.Core.Service.Telegram.Common.TelegramBot`1.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<SendTextMessageAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\MelkRadar\src\MelkRadar\Core\MelkRadar.Core.Service\Telegram\Common\TelegramBot.cs:line 113
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Polly.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass181_0`1.<<ExecuteAsyncInternal>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Policy.Async.cs:line 0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Polly.RetrySyntaxAsync.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<WaitAndRetryAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetrySyntaxAsync.cs:line 545
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Polly.Retry.RetryEngine.<ImplementationAsync>d__1`1.MoveNext() in C:\projects\polly\src\Polly.Shared\Retry\RetryEngineAsync.cs:line 29
```

Can any one help me to fix this problem?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the server closing the connection when the client disconnects?  The listener in the server is only allowing a maximum of 400 connections.  So when more than 400 connections are made the server is not allowing more connections.  So you have to close the connections on the server before more connections are allowed.

Comment: @jdweng But why wasn't it happening before?

Comment: May be this is the 1st time you got 400 requests.

Comment: No, I'm sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved when I stopped my VPN!
I don't know how it really influences my requests and the connection between telegram servers and my application. but the problem seems to be caused by the VPN.